# CSS sprite empty spaces underneath

Tags: html, css, sprite, css-sprites

I'm having problem with my sprite css, I've provided a jsfiddle so you can see what i mean. So as you can observe there are spaces beneath the image and I can't seem to find what the problem is. Is this because of the positioning? I tried using float but it only reduces the spaces.

What I want to accomplish is to remove the spaces underneath because it really looks ugly on my website having empty spaces.

PS. Also if I use absolute, It will overlap the text in my site.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nattygurl/b38gha3h/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
<div class="arrow-sprite"></div>
<div class="arrow-sprite-2"></div>
<div class="arrow-sprite-3"></div>
<div class="arrow-sprite-4"></div>
<div class="arrow-sprite-5"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-sprite {
    background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) 19px 7px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 441px;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    left: 139px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.arrow-sprite-2 {
    background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) -1381px -12px;
    width: 475px;
    height: 419px;
    position: relative;
    top: -375px;
    left: 507px;
    z-index: 4;
}
.arrow-sprite-3 {
    background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) -430px -8px;
    width: 387px;
    height: 416px;
    position: relative;
    top: -523px;
    left: 134px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.arrow-sprite-4 {
    background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) -900px 12px;
    width: 442px;
    height: 427px;
    position: relative;
    top: -908px;
    left: 418px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.arrow-sprite-5 {
    background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) 30px -438px;
    width: 519px;
    height: 490px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1529px;
    left: 239px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.arrow-sprite:hover, .arrow-sprite-2:hover,.arrow-sprite-3:hover,.arrow-sprite-4:hover {
    filter: contrast(160%);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: What's causing the space is that the sprites are stacked on top of each other, which is the default behaviour of `div` as they occupy 100% width, pushing the next sibling element below it. Modifying the `top` property does not affect this. 

If you get rid of the `top` and `left` properties of the sprites CSS it will be easier to visualize this in the developer console. 

How exactly do you want to position these sprites?

As a side note, your sprites don't load in jsfiddle as external linking is disallowed from your site.

Comment: Image you used for sprite is asking for user name password. please provide the another image

Comment: @FuriousD Actually I'm using the top and left properties, so i can position .arrow-sprite, .arrow-sprite-2, .arrow-sprite-3 and .arrow-sprite-4 on top of .arrow-sprite-5. It actually worked but yeah it created spaces underneath it.

Comment: Yep so adjusting the left and top on a `position: relative` element won't change the space it occupies, just where it appears . What are you trying to achieve? There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @Bhushanwagh updated it already

Comment: @FuriousD This is what i'm trying to acheive (http://prntscr.com/g5pwtp) and here's the sprite img (http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png)

Comment: The best way to handle that is to make all the sprite elements absolute, and to add a height to the container they sit within so that they don't overlap the rest of the content.

Comment: @FuriousD Thank you! I get what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `row`'s position to `relative`, then set the sprites to `position:absolute;` and readjusting the `top` positions for the sprites will do the trick.

> Also set a specific `height` for the `row` so that it won't overlap
>   any other content below.

Run the snippet below:

```css
.arrow-sprite {
        background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) 19px 7px;
        width: 450px;
        height: 441px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 11px;
        left: 139px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .arrow-sprite-2 {
        background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) -1381px -12px;
        width: 475px;
        height: 419px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 65px;
        left: 507px;
        z-index: 4;
    }
    .arrow-sprite-3 {
        background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) -430px -8px;
        width: 387px;
        height: 416px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 333px;
        left: 134px;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .arrow-sprite-4 {
        background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) -900px 12px;
        width: 442px;
        height: 427px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 358px;
        left: 418px;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .arrow-sprite-5 {
        background: no-repeat url(http://i.imgur.com/O8R881E.png) 30px -438px;
        width: 519px;
        height: 490px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 169px;
        left: 239px;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .arrow-sprite:hover, .arrow-sprite-2:hover,.arrow-sprite-3:hover,.arrow-sprite-4:hover {
        filter: contrast(160%);
        transition: 0.5s ease-in;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;position: relative;height: 850px;">
<div class="arrow-sprite"></div>
<div class="arrow-sprite-2"></div>
<div class="arrow-sprite-3"></div>
<div class="arrow-sprite-4"></div>
<div class="arrow-sprite-5"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.
Deadlights jack lad schooner scallywag dance the hempen jig carouser broadside cable strike colors. Bring a spring upon her cable holystone blow the man down spanker Shiver me timbers to go on account lookout wherry doubloon chase. Belay yo-ho-ho keelhaul squiffy black spot yardarm spyglass sheet transom heave to.
Trysail Sail ho Corsair red ensign hulk smartly boom jib rum gangway. Case shot Shiver me timbers gangplank crack Jennys tea cup ballast Blimey lee snow crow's nest rutters. Fluke jib scourge of the seven seas boatswain schooner gaff booty Jack Tar transom spirits.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome, please also see the updated answer.